# Deleting password from Keychain in terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, keychain, macos

I'm having trouble deleting the github credentials from Keychain Access. Keychain Access just freezes everytime I try. Is there a command to force deletion of an item in the Keychain from the terminal?

Comment: Perhaps you question should be how to fix Keychain?

Comment: Why would I ask a more general question for a specific case?

Comment: Because you're not solving the problem just working around it. Others could have a similar problem so it would help them too.

Comment: Problem was definitely solved. It was just a crude solution. Consider, what if someone would like to know how to delete a password from terminal for a _different_ reason? This questions will still help that general case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may first try to find the credentials (or better the blob):

```
security find-internet-password -l "github.com"  /Users/user_name/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Then delete them with:

```
security delete-internet-password -l "github.com"  /Users/user_name/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

If you have several github.com items you have to repeat this. Create a backup of your login.keychain (or better the whole Keychain folder) before proceeding.