# Search for keychain password via Terminal/shell?

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, password, keychain

Is there any way to do a partial (wildcard) search for a password from my iCloud keychain or Chrome via shell?

E.g., given "foo" I would like to find all keychain items (of any kind, including "Web form password" and "Internet password") where the URL ("Where") or "Name" or "Account" contains "foo".

I have tried `security find-internet-password -l 'example.com'` and all kinds of variations but everything results in

```
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Looked at [Deleting password from Keychain in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235415/119271) and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378713/119271 (as suggested by https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan) but they did not help.

Comment: Neither of those threads answers my question or provides a working solution.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you tried from the Q&A linked above, and how it didn't work?

Comment: Hi @Dan.  Your question is about *searching keychain via Terminal*.  Both Qs above contain information on searching and manipulating keychain via Terminal.  If those aren't sufficient, can you provide additional details?